# What a peculiar family

Tags: riddle, story, knowledge

I once met a family, well actually only the kids, quite a *strange* bunch. They said Dad was a busy man, so they were often alone.
I asked about Mom, and they just shrugged their shoulders and shook their heads.

I got a chance to have a brief word with them each, at least most of them, pretty *interesting* kids.

**The conversations I had:**

- "Hi, I'm **Patrick**, they say I'm the eldest but no one knows who really is." (I noticed a drop of blood on his arm so I asked what happened). "Oh my stupid brother **Fred** pricked me with his dumb yellow pin he wears... and by the way don't listen to a word **Luke** says, he's a dunce". (He turned to leave immediately, and I noticed some foil in his back pocket with the wording -va slightly visible)
- "Hey, **Fredrick** here. What's hangin'?" (I almost didn't reply, I couldn't help but notice he was staring intently at my watch). I asked if he needed to know the time. "Nah nah, (he started to leave) by the way, our brother **Bobby** is dead, so you ain't gunna meet him." (And then he left, he still had that pin on, so you could see the little red shine from **Patrick's** blood).
- (Curious about the one who passed, I decided to bring it up to the next kid). I asked **Dan** what happened to their brother **Bobby**. "It was bad... whole body ripped apart. They say it may have been some sort of wolf or wild animal... My sister **Susan** actually blamed me, can you believe that? I loved **Bobby**, just hated that he always got the attention for being the big guy, our protective brother..." (As he left I couldn't help but think about how unfortunate that is... and why did his sister blame him?)
- "The name's **Luke**, sorry about my other siblings. If you've got a question just ask me, I'm the smart one. But, don't listen to them when they tell you I'm the worst." I asked why they said that and he avoided the question, instead informing me that, "Oh our sister **Gale** doesn't feel like talking to you". And he walked away, not so helpful after all. (I glanced over at **Gale** and noticed a light blue ribbon in her hair, but she looked away when we made eye contact).
- The last one I talked to was the girl named **Susan**. "Hey there. (She spoke soft, and was seemingly analyzing me, as if there was something she wanted to figure out about me)". I asked why she blamed **Dan** for the death of their brother but she dismissed that saying, "They're not important to me right now", as if they recently upset her. It seemed she gave me one last look-over before also walking back, not sure what that was about.
- As a last attempt to uncover some info about **Bobby** I called over to them and asked what he was like. I only got a muttering of words from **Patrick**. I picked up a couple things like "An-" and "Frus-".

I was very confused by this group of siblings; I almost wanted to call for services to get them some help for them but by the time I looked down at my phone and back up again, the *not-so-normal* group was gone.

***Who are these kids?***

Hint 1:

> **First of all**, emphasis is important.

Hint 2:

> Did **Dan** say wolf with some excitement, or was I hearing things?

Hint 3:

> The way that **Bobby** died seemed pretty important, but why?

Hint 4:

> Colorfully **hidden details**, yet right in front of you.

Hint 5:

> **God I**, could go for some candy right about now.

Comment: I have a tingling feeling inside that this is somehow related to physics or chemistry. Or maybe I'm just hungry

Comment: I can't do much about you being hungry but I can nudge you away from the train of thought if you'd like ;)

Comment: Should this have the "knowledge" tag on it?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I added it, but you could possibly figure it out without external sources. Depends on whatcha know

Comment: If it depends on whatcha know, the knowledge tag is almost certainly appropriate.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Fair enough, I added it. I'll add more hints on tomorrow if it's still without guesses.. Which I have to do without giving too much away

Comment: Though I have not read or watched Game of Thrones, I suspect that this puzzle is about the seven kingdoms/houses shown in GoT.

Comment: @rvd While that's an interesting approach, that is not the right track

Comment: Is the "candy" reference likely to require knowledge from a particular country?

Comment: @Donnelle it should not no

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The kids are

> the Seven Deadly Sins

Patrick is

> Gluttony (candy bar in pocket)

Fredrick is

> Greed (yellow pin, stares intently at watch)

Dan is

> Envy (hates that Bobby always got attention)

Bobby is

> Wrath ("An-"ger, "Frus-"tration)

Luke is

> Pride (smart one, just ask me)

Gale is

> Sloth (light-blue ribbon, doesn't feel like talking)

Susan is

> Lust (analyzing me, last look-over)

Comment: That's it. Nice. +1 I am not sure why those names are chosen though.

Comment: Seems awfully plausible, but then so far as I can see the emphasized things ("strange", "interesting", etc.) and children's names are just red herrings, and it's not clear to me what the business about the children's parents is meant to mean (perhaps their father is the devil, a busy chap indeed?).

Comment: I'll give it to you that you got who they are but I want you to figure out the reasoning for the names too. And for @GarethMcCaughan (the reason I bolded the hint first of all, was to push people to look at the first letters of emphasized things)

Comment: @n_palum But how? There are 3 G's in the seven sins also one E, but only one name starting with G and none with E. That makes the names red herring's right? Or may be unclear clues? But well, we have the answer anyway :)

Comment: And for @Moghwyn and Techidot the hint I would give for figuring out the names is to think physical... Pat should be the easiest, from there the rest should come... I'm also curious if you know about the colors or if you are just including them as part of your description of each kid.

Comment: The italic are separate from the bold. S-trange, I-nteresting, N-otsonormal. That was the hint to them being the sins as a wholes.

Comment: @n_palum Hmm. In that case either steganography or enigmatic tag would have been helpful.

Comment: I don't think this was so enigmatic as to need the enigmatic tag (but that one's always a bit subjective). Unless there's more steganography than just the s-i-n thing, I don't see that that tag's needed either.

Comment: @Techidiot sorry, still newer to the site and not familiar with every single tag.. will make note of that for future riddles... All feedback is welcome! I'm not sure if this one was bad or something since it took a lot of push to get some anwers

Comment: @n_palum Well, the answer fits the story. So, well done :) All the best for the next.

Comment: I'll give him the accepted answer eventually, but I'll save the bounty for if the names reasoning is figured out. and thanks

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Being unrelated to Christianity, it wouldn't have been possible for many(at least me) to guess what was going on, without any context or the *sin* thing.

Comment: I was thinking about 7 deadly sins, but I rejected it, because it fits other things too and there is no stego/enigma tag :(

Comment: Hence the "knowledge" tag, which is certainly very appropriate.

Comment: As for whether it's good or bad, I'm reserving judgement on that until I see where the names come from, and whether the other incidental details (parents, Bobby's death, ...) have neat explanations in terms of the intended answer.

Comment: Aha. There's a traditional association between deadly sins and (1) animals and (2) colours. The first letters of the animals match the first letters of the children.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Welp just deleted the comment asking but yeah that would be what I am going for... I.e Bobby the Bear... and I'll just give it and say that each sin has a punishment associated with it.. Wrath being dismemberment, hence the significance of his method of death. Dan the Dog being excited about wolves because they are similar to dogs...

Comment: LION = PRIDE = Luke, 
DOG = ENVY = Dan,
BEAR = ANGER = Bobby,
GOAT = SLOTH = Gale,
FROG = GREED = Fredrick,
PIG = GLUTTONY = Patrick,
SNAKE = LUST = Susan,

Comment: @Techidiot Yep that would be them.. The colors are also the associated colors but those were just supposed to be tiny hints to connect them more.. As for the parent situation, it's a little weird.. Some say that the Devil would be the Dad, some say that humans invented the 7, so it's not that important of a detail.

Comment: I had also considered the Deadly Sins, but didn't think the descriptions really fitted. Especially, why is Bobby dead? The fact that he has died made me think about sets of coins where one is no longer in circulation and similar sets where one of seven is "dead".

Comment: @MOehm I went with the death (albeit being a slight stretch) to show a different aspect of the sins (the punishments associated with them). Maybe it would have been better to say he killed someone by that method and was in jail or something.. But that's hindsight.

Comment: I see, so the death refers to the "deadly" in the Deadly Sins.

Comment: That too.. that's part of how they got their name. It was said that if you committed this you would suffer the punishments that correlated to each one, all deadly punishments.

Comment: Yes, but it's the sinners who suffer death, not the sins themselves. Anyway, I was misdirected by Bobby's death. (Misdirection is not necessarily a bad thing. And I understand that you couldn't make the characteristics of the sins too obvious.)

Comment: Yeah I know, but I felt it was a bit appropriate with misdirecting, since I was already personifying them as kids/animals and it was tricky to not make things to obvious.. If I had said Patrick had chocolate smeared on his face, people would probably have gotten it instantly. I was trying to be a little more layered/difficult this time.,

Answer (score 0):

Not complete.

Hint 1:

> "First of all, emphasis is important."
>  What words are emphasised?
>
>  *strange* *interesting*
>  **The conversations I had:**
>  **Patrick**  **Fred**  **Luke**
>  **Fredrick**  **Bobby**  **Patrick**
>  **Dan** **Bobby**  **Susan** **Bobby**
>  **Luke** **Gale**  **Gale**
>  **Susan**  **Dan**
>  **Bobby**  **Patrick**
>  *not-so-normal*
>  ***Who are these kids?***
>
>  The italics would suggest anagrams?

Hint 2:

> No idea.

Hint 3:

> No idea.

Hint 4:

> Colourfully hidden details
>  Patrick - red blood
>  Fred - yellow pin
>  Gale - light blue ribbon

Hint 5:

> **God I**, plus the -va from Patrick's pocket, plus the candy hint = Godiva, as in Godiva chocolate.

Thoughts:

> **Hot**
>  "I noticed some foil in his back pocket with the wording -va slightly visible)"
>  Does this mean it *ended* in "va"?
>  If it's candy, the only thing I can find that it might be is Godiva chocolate.
>
>  **Cold**
>  yellow pin, as in "yellow pin fish"?
>
>   are they countries?  Bobby being a big country who got split into smaller countries?

Comment: Let me know if you want any sort of response to things you "figure out" or think you have

Comment: "Hot" "cold" welcome!  I'm pretty stumped.  Mostly just noodling to see if anyone jumps in to brainstorm.

Comment: I am all for the brainstorming! I am kinda proud of this one, but I'm aware it's hard. For hint 1, other than listing emphasized things, you're kinda cold. For hint 4, warm and cold, think beyond just color. Also I'll just be blunt and say the 'red shine' is for flavor, it's irrelevant.

Comment: For your thoughts so far: first bit is hot, rest is cold

Answer (score 0):

Let me just collate what we know about the children so far.

There are seven of them:

> **Patrick**, who is possibly the oldest, and (as @Donnelle found) he has a Godiva chocolate bar in his back pocket.
>  **Fredrick**, who pricked Patrick with his yellow pin, and seems to have an interest in watches or time.
>  **Bobby**, who was the "protector" of the children and probably the largest physically, but was torn apart by a wolf and killed.
>  **Dan**, who seems to have an interest in wolves.
>  **Susan**, who is soft-spoken and analytical, and apparently blames Dan for Bobby's death.
>  **Luke**, who believes himself to be smart, but whom Patrick believes is an idiot.
>  **Gale**, who wears a light blue ribbon and doesn't want to talk to us.

I'll throw out some actual ideas shortly, but hopefully putting everything in one place will make it easier for someone to spot the links or something.